How do I install a pip package on a machine without Internet access?
I'm working on a Linux machine without (direct) Internet access. I want to pip install foo for some pypi package foo, but - obviously, that won't work. I have, of course, other machines which are connected the Internet.
How would I go about determining what files need to be downloaded, downloading them and installing them once they're on the isolated machine?
Notes:

I'd rather get a Python-version-independent answer, but if it is version-dependent, let's assume Python 3.6 or later.
This question sounds the same, but it's actually about installing pip istelf.


You can ask pip to download a .whl wheel file (and its dependency wheel files) instead of installing it:
pip download foo

(on an Internet-connected system, replacing foo with your actual package as appropriate).
Then copy the downloaded files to the off-line system, and install with
pip install --no-index --find-links . foo

You can replace . with the path to the directory with the wheel(s), and foo with the package name.
In both cases, foo can be replaced with -r /path/to/requirements.txt. pip download supports a variety of options to specify the version of Python to download for, the architecture etc.

Will the download command acquire all dependencies (other than pip itself)? Won't it go by the dependencies on the system with the access to the internet?

It’s not clear from the documentation, but in my tests it downloads everything, ignoring installed dependencies. For example, in a clean venv, pip install idna installs idna-3.6, and a subsequent pip download sphinx downloads the idna-3.6 wheel even though the module is installed.
